# C++ First GUI app

Tags: c++, user-interface

Currently I am developing a simple console bubble-breaker game and I would like to go further and create some kind of GUI for it. Could you recommend the best and easiest way or a tutorial on creating a GUI app and simple shapes? Would you mind sharing some good c++ libraries that exist out there?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like something Google would do well.

Comment: I recommend using [Qt](http://qt-project.org/downloads)

Answer (score 3):

To create GUI games, you would likely need a library.
Library is a set of code that are written to provide extra function, like creating GUI applications.
I would recommend SDL for developing C++ games.

Here is a pretty good tutorial for learning SDL: http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Qt libraries**](http://qt-project.org/) and [**Graphics view framework**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html).They are really easy to start and easy to learn. With graphics view framework you can write simple 2D games.

> Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework for developers
>   using C++ or QML, a CSS & JavaScript like language. Qt Creator is the
>   supporting Qt IDE.

If you want to bring life to your 2D games use [**Box2D library**](http://box2d.org/) for c++.

> Box2D is an open source C++ engine for simulating rigid bodies in 2D.
>   Box2D is developed by Erin Catto and has the zlib license.